# Why does memcmp() return 256 for a difference of 1?

Tags: c, linux, macos, unix

So I have to recreate the memcmp() function using C and my function works as expected. It returns the difference of the first character that does not match in both strings.

**My function:**

```
int ft_memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char   *ptr1;
    unsigned char   *ptr2;

    ptr1 = (unsigned char *)s1;
    ptr2 = (unsigned char *)s2;
    while (n && (*ptr1 == *ptr2))
    {
        ptr1++;
        ptr2++;
        n--;
    }
    if (n == 0)
        return (0);
    else
        return (*ptr1 - *ptr2);
}
```

**My main:**

```
int main(void)
{
    const char  *s1 = "acc";
    const char  *s2 = "abc";
    int         res;

    res = memcmp(s1, s2, 3); 
    printf("%i\n", res);

    return (0);
}
```

So this main will return 256, but if you use my function (ft_memcmp) you get 1. Obviously the difference is 1 and not 256, but why does the original function return 256? With a difference of 2, I get 512...

Comment: Note: `return` is a statement, not a function. The parenthesis you use are part of the expression, not the statement. They are not required for the statement. Their use is not recommended for simple expressions, as they complicate reading.

Comment: Okay, fair comment. I totally agree. However, my college uses something called the "Norm" and it requires us to put parenthesis when using 'return' as well as spaces between keywords and parenthesis. For example, 'while ()' and not 'while()'....

Comment: @Olaf it is your personal opinion. Let us focus here on technical aspects of the question even though really very rarely you will see return (0), I do agree it should read return 0, obviously.

Comment: `*ptr1 - *ptr2` will provide the wrong sign answer on platforms that use an `unsigned char` and `unsigned` of the same size (e.g. some graphics processors) due to mathematical overflow.  `(*ptr1 > *ptr2) - (*ptr1 < *ptr2)` is an idiomatic alternative..

Comment: @chux - So would you recommend I use square bracket notation instead? EG. `ptr1[i] - ptr2[j]` Would that be a viable alternative as well?

Comment: `*ptr1 - *ptr2` and (keeping pointers constant, but incrementing an index) `ptr1[some_int] - ptr2[some_int]` are the same.  So do not see that as an improvement over `(*ptr1 > *ptr2) - (*ptr1 < *ptr2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does memcmp() return 256 for a difference of 1?

First, as answered by [@where_is_tftp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37191706/2410359), the only thing `memcmp()` needs to return is `0`, *some* positive number and *some* negative number on a compare.

The 256 instead of 1 - certainly because of optimization.

A good `memcmp()` takes advantage of doing its compare using types wider than `char` as it can.

Example: After considering alignment and the overall length, the first compare (using 32-bit `unsigned`) sees a difference, not in the 1's position (bit 0), but the 256's postilion (bit 8).  Since returning 256 is just as valid as 1, no need to simplify.  Remember that `memcmp()` is platform specific and its implementation can do the things that C code cannot - like safely access outside the array.  Other details omitted here.

```
    byte 3         2        1        0
    don't care    'c'      'c'      'a'
  - don't care    'c'      'b'      'a'
    -----------------------------------
  = don't care     0        1        0
  &    0          0xFF     0xFF     0xFF
    -----------------------------------
  =    0           0        1        0   --> 256
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a statement about exact value of non-zero return value from memcmp beside it's sign (either on man pages or Open Group pages):

> The sign of a non-zero return value shall be determined by the sign of
>   the difference between the values of the first pair of bytes (both
>   interpreted as type unsigned char) that differ in the objects being
>   compared.
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> The memcmp() function shall return an **integer greater** than, **equal** to,
>   **or less than 0**, if the object pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal
>   to, or less than the object pointed to by s2, respectively.

Nothing says here it is the decimal difference between characters.

Comment: "difference between the values of the first pair of bytes ... that differ in the objects being compared." It states "difference between the values". How else would I find a difference if not with decimals/integers?

Comment: @Kbam7 the [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) maybe, or [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: @Kbam7: 1) C does not have "decimal" variables. No wonder, as the language relies on binary computers. Decimal is just an input/output representation. `char` and realted are also integer types.

Comment: Yes, I understand that char and related types stem from integers. i.e 'a' == 97. But now, can anyone tell me why I am getting '256' when I use memcmp on Linux? And why my friend gets '1' when he uses memcmp on his Mac? We both used the same code but get different answers?

Comment: @Kbam7 "How else would I find a difference if not with decimals/integers? " --> with [compare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191355/why-does-memcmp-return-256-for-a-difference-of-1#comment61916751_37191355).

Comment: @Kbam7 because this is not defined what integer value is returned your C implementation (compiler, library) may return 256 and implmentation of memcmp function on your friend's machine may return 1, both are greater than zero which must hold, as it is defined